# Possible to specify radius when targeting zip codes with Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Using Facebook Ads API I'm creating an ad targeting a specific zip code as demonstrated in the code below. All works fine, but when double checking manually through the Ads Manager I noticed `radius` is being ignored and only people in the exact zip code region are targeted.

Is it not possible to specify a radius when targeting zip codes?

```
[geo_locations] => Array
    (

        [zips] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => BE:2020
                        [radius] => 10
                        [distance_unit] => mile
                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: Random thought: since a zip code is a polygon (not a point), having a radius would give you something fairly strange looking. Perhaps that's why it's not implemented.

Comment: @barrycarter Good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't target by zip and the radius, it's only as you said targeting within that zip (you can specify multiple zips if you want to expand it).  You can target with a specific address/city/state or lat/long coordinates to specify a point to use a radius off of.

You can find databases of zip codes to download that specify lat/long coordinates (I assume of some sort of mid/center point?) that I've considered using to get around this before when I wanted a 25 mile radius around 12345 etc.